# Can I use styled components to style react-notifications?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-notifications

I'm using styled components in a project and have just added  react-notifications. When I try to use styled components to style my NotificationContainer and its descendants. I instead get an un-styled base NotificationContainer. Am I making a mistake, or is react-notifications simply incompatible?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {NotificationContainer, NotificationManager} from 'react-notifications';
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledNotificationContainer = styled(NotificationContainer)`
    background-color: orange;
`
export default class Example extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <StyledNotificationContainer />
        )
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        NotificationManager.info('Example')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, [styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components) says that you can style any third party component using it as long as this components can consume `className` props (this is how styled is doing it's magic). [react-notification docs](https://github.com/minhtranite/react-notifications#notificationcontainer-props) says that `NotificationContainer` accepts only two props, and [none of them is className](https://github.com/minhtranite/react-notifications/blob/master/src/NotificationContainer.js#L43) .

You can't use it is **incompatible**.